# QS Stringify with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, query-string, vue-router

Im having issue implementing the `qs` package from https://github.com/ljharb/qs in VueJS.

```
let test = qs.stringify({ test: ['a','b','c'] });
```

This gives me a url such as `https://example.dev/#/search?test[0]=a&test[1]=b&test[2]=c`

When I paste this URL into the address bar it gets changed to `https://example.dev/#/search?test%5B0%5D=a&test%5B1%5D=b&test%5B2%5D=c`

Below is how I am handling the parsing of the URL

```
let routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: require('./pages/search'), 
    parseQuery: function (queryString) {
      return qs.parse(queryString);
    }
  },
];
```

But everything returns as `undefined`

```
console.log('this.$route.query.test = '+this.$route.query.test);
//this.$route.query.test = undefined
```

I've tried it with the `{ encode: false }` flag on and off, but I just can't get past this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't you search for `parseQuery` instead of `query`?

Comment: Do you mean changing it to `parseQuery: function (parseQuery) {
      return qs.parse(parseQuery);
    }` ? That has the same outcome

Comment: just conole.log `this.$route` and see if has `query` and `test` props

Comment: I just get [object Object]

Comment: you shouldn't get that unless something is wrong, check where that is coming from maybe post an example with more of your code

Comment: Whats weird is in the Vue developer console `$route` is showing `query:Object
test[0]:"a"
test[1]:"b"
test[2]:"c"`

Comment: Did you figure this out by now? if not, I may be able to help, as I just implemented for my project. Bit `tricky` :)